# How can I run an xcode application on my iDevice without signing? Jailbroken Device

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak

I have changed some settings in xcode to be able to create apps without signed code. But when I put the app on my iPhone 6, it crashes on startup. I already installed Appsync, but that doesn't work. So I read about ldid. I've installed ldid through cydia and connected with ssh. But I get this error:

```
  ./minimal/mapping.h(54): _assert(false); errno=21
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Apps need to be signed... Either by a developer identity or by the MAS or dosas identity.

What happens when you run it through the debugger? Where exactly dos the debugger get halted? Are there any symbols for us to see? i.e. when it crashes, download the crash logs via Xcode and have a look at them. Usually, if an app gets buggy, re-compile it WITHOUT stripping the symbols (in build settings), then the crash log will be easier to read.

You get the common name to sign your app by going into keychain access, double clicking on the certificate you want (I suggest the developer ID one)...

[image]

One thing to note though.. I you have any embedded bundles, frameworks or XPC services, you should add `--deep` to the end of the coding command, so

instead of: `codesign --force -s "Developer ID Application: Your Certificate Common Name" /path/to/your/Application.app`

you would use:

`codesign --force --deep -s "Developer ID Application: Your Certificate Common Name" /path/to/your/Application.app`

Which, in short, recursively signs

Comment: While my iPhone is not connected to my Mac, all works fine. When I choose my iPhone it gives me the error: ".process launch failed: failed to get the task for process 1567". Just choosing "iOS Device" says something like "Apps for iOS8.1 SDK have to be signed".

Archieving the app and try to put it on my iPhone with iTunes will install the app, but on lunch it shows black screen and takes me to the homescreen. I thinks thats the normal result for running unsigned apps.

Comment: sign it from terminal then: `codesign --force -s "Developer ID Application: Your Certificate Common Name"  /path/to/your/Application.app`.. You get the part in quotes (you need to use the quotes tho) from "Keychain Access", its the part I've highlighted in red in my answer.